# How to change JavaScript context in chrome devtools with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need so JavaScript context in chrome devtools always point to localhost. By default it points to top context.

I've created basic chrome extension, with specific permissions to debugger and devtools.

Comment: Extensions can't manipulate the UI of devtools.

Comment: Could you suggest something else?

Comment: If you want to automate this action, you can use an external tool such as AutoHotkey in Windows. Or you can edit the devtools source code inside resources.pak file.